# how to restore mysql db a day before

Tags: mysql

can anyone please tell me how i can restore the mysql db to one day earlier because some mistake happened in the script and one of all the colums of particular parameter got affected please help ,Server version: 5.0.85-log
MySQL client version: 5.2.10-MariaDB
PHP extension: mysqli

Comment: do you have backup of the day before?

Comment: no i dont that is the problem if i had i could have restored it now i am in big trouble plz help me any other way

Comment: This might get better answers on http://dba.stackexchange.com ...Though frankly if you don't have a backup or transaction logs I suspect you're on your own to correct the data.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to your previous MariaDB backup, and reload from the binary log until the point where the mistake happened. If the binary log is not active, or you do not have a backup at all, then you are on your own!

First, reload from your latest dump file:

```
mysql -u root -p < dump_file
```

Next, look in the dump file to find the binary log co-ordinates, and re-execute the events until the point you need.

Then, look through the binary log (with mysqlbinlog) to see the point where the mistake happened. This is the the point in which to stop.

For example, if the co-ordinates in the dump file are as follows:

```
-- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='binlog.002003', MASTER_LOG_POS=96456;
```

and the point to stop is at 104342 (this is the first invalid command)

Then you will need to run the following command to restore:

```
mysqlbinlog --start-position=96456 --stop-position=104342 binlog.002003 | mysql -u root -p
```

You may also need to run over more than one binlog - see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlbinlog/ for more mysqlbinlog usage and syntax details.

Comment: mysql != mariadb. to be precise mariadb >= mysql